# C program to search for a track in an array of tracks

Tags: c, string, input, stdin, fgets

I have a program, which should output the track name and number based on a text input (e.g. input 'town' should output "Track 1: 'Newark, Newark - a wonderful town'") but the output is currently empty (nothing is returned, the program just stops executing without any errors). Here's the program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

char tracks[][80] = {
"I left my heart in Harvard Med School",
"Newark, Newark - a wonderful town",
"Dancing with a Dork",
"From here to maternity",
"The girl from Iwo Jima",
};

void find_track(char search_for[])
{
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++){
        if (strstr(tracks[i], search_for))
            printf("Track %i: '%s'\n", i, tracks[i]);
    }
}

int main()
{
    char search_for[80];
    printf("Search for: ");
    fgets(search_for, 80, stdin);
    find_track(search_for);
    return 0;
}
```

Please help :)

Comment: `fgets` keeps the new-line at the end. Remove it before you pass `search_for` to `find_track`.

Comment: (For how to do that, [look here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28462221/2979617).)

Comment: There's no meaning in writing an answer after such comments these days lol

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
fgets(search_for, 80, stdin);
```

catches the `\n` newline character trailing the proper string input made by the press to `Return` and writes it into `search_for`.

---

The best way to remove it is best-explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28462221/12139179) to [Removing trailing newline character from fgets() input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2693776/removing-trailing-newline-character-from-fgets-input/28462221#28462221).

Use `strcspn()` by:

```
search_for[strcspn(search_for, "\n")] = 0;
```

before the call to

```
find_track(search_for);
```

to remove or better said replace it with `\0`.

---

The whole code shall be then:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

char tracks[][80] = {
"I left my heart in Harvard Med School",
"Newark, Newark - a wonderful town",
"Dancing with a Dork",
"From here to maternity",
"The girl from Iwo Jima",
};

void find_track(char search_for[])
{
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++){
        if (strstr(tracks[i], search_for))
            printf("Track %i: '%s'\n", i, tracks[i]);
    }
}

int main()
{
    char search_for[80];
    printf("Search for: ");
    fgets(search_for, 80, stdin);
    search_for[strcspn(search_for, "\n")] = 0;    // here is the change.
    find_track(search_for);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for providing clarification and the finished code!

Comment: I´m glad that I could help you. Does it work now as expected? Don´t forget to also up-vote the linked answer, which provided the base of the solution. ;-)

Comment: It does indeed! And that's the first thing I did when I followed the link. :)